# Meaning of "implying" in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

> The capacity to cause or change certain types of human behavior by *implying* or using physical or psychological means to induce compliance.

I consulted various dictionaries but the definitions given do not clarify the meaning.

1. to suggest that something is true, without saying this directly
2. if a fact, event etc implies something, it shows that it is likely to be true
3. if one thing implies another, it proves that the second thing exists

So my question is, how do you *imply* a means to do something.

Comment: If I stand in front of you waving a nightstick about, I'm (visually) implying that I might use it on you. This might induce you to be more compliant (without me actually using it).

Comment: Agreed. It doesn't make sense to me either. If you imply that invasive means might be used, you're already using psychological means, and compliance with some set of rules cannot but be involved. Note that we must, without a caveat to the contrary, assume that 'implying' was italicised in the original. Also, you need to give an attributed link for the quote.

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks for the heads-up. I was concentrating too much on getting the right number of syllables in _apos ..._ (I think there are variants, even for such a rare bird).

Comment: Note that, as your examples show, there are conflicting senses of 'imply'; this sometimes leads to ambiguities not clarified by context, especially in writing.

Comment: Your sense that the word was used incorrectly is quite justified. Given that the author says 'implying or using', chances are that by 'implying' the author meant something that falls short of actual use of these means. What was intended was probably something like ' . . . by threatening to use or actually using . . . means', but that is only a guess. Given that the author's mistake was not of a kind that is frequently made, or illuminating of English language and usage in general, the question will probably be closed.

Comment: The quotation appears to be a dictionary definition of "to threaten" *So my question is, how do you imply a means to do something?* Consider: "I was pushing and pulling the door, but it would not open. Peter looked at me and, as he looked, he glanced at a key on the table and smiled." -> Peter is implying that you should use the key.